# Android Room with RxJava handle empty query result

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-room

Trying to test new Android Room librarty with RxJava adapter. And I want to handle result if my query returns 0 objects from DB:

So here is DAO method:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM auth_info")
fun getAuthInfo(): Flowable<AuthResponse>
```

And how I handle it:

```
database.authDao()
    .getAuthInfo()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .switchIfEmpty { Log.d(TAG, "IS EMPTY") }
    .firstOrError()
    .subscribe(
            { authResponse -> Log.d(TAG, authResponse.token) },
            { error -> Log.d(TAG, error.message) })
```

My DB is empty, so I expect .switchIfEmty() to work, but none of handling methods is firing. Neither .subscribe() nor .switchIfEmpty()

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Db Flowables are observable (so they keep dispatching if database changes) so it never completes. You can try returning `List<AuthResponse>`. We've considered back porting an optional but decided not to do it, at least for now. Instead, we'll probably add support for Optional in different known libraries.

Comment: You should consider an alternative behavior for this feature. I want to get Flowable.empty() when the result of request is empty.

Comment: Does room query return an non-null, empty list of size 0 then?

Comment: @Query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM User")
Flowable<Integer> getCount();

why doesn’t it return 0 if there are no users? I would like to track the number of users ..

Comment: We have been using the List<T> solution but it's still a hack. Has Room figured out a better way to do it?

Comment: I think this makes rxjava and room useless, if I make a query to db I spect to get a result even if there is no data. using of Maybe or Single breaks reactive approach

Answer (score 10):

In version 1.0.0-alpha5, room added support of `Maybe` and `Single` to DAOs, so now you can write something like

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM auth_info")
fun getAuthInfo(): Maybe<AuthResponse>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)

Answer (score 0):

`switchIfEmpty` takes as parameter a `Publisher<AuthResponse>`. Through SAM-conversion your given anonymous function is turned into this class. However it does not follow the behavior expected from a `Publisher` so it will not work as expected.

Replace it with a correct implementation like `Flowable.empty().doOnSubscribe { Log.d(TAG, "IS EMPTY") }` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some wrapper for result. For example:

```
public Single<QueryResult<Transaction>> getTransaction(long id) {
            return createSingle(() -> database.getTransactionDao().getTransaction(id))
                    .map(QueryResult::new);
}

    public class QueryResult<D> {
            public D data;
            public QueryResult() {}

            public QueryResult(D data) {
                this.data = data;
            }

            public boolean isEmpty(){
                return data != null;
            }
 }

protected <T> Single<T> createSingle(final Callable<T> func) {
            return Single.create(emitter -> {
                try {
                    T result = func.call();
                    emitter.onSuccess(result);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "Error of operation with db");
                }
            });
}
```

And use it like 'Single' in this case you will get result in any case. Use:

```
dbStorage.getTransaction(selectedCoin.getId())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(r -> {
                         if(!r.isEmpty()){
                           // we have some data from DB
                         } else {
                       }
                    })
```